# select2 and removing several options from another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i have this code in this url:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("select[name=ClientsCities]").change(function() {
                    $(this).value="";
                    $("select[name=Clients] option").each(function(){
                        if ($(this).parent().is( "div" )) {
                            $(this).unwrap();
                        }
                    });


                    thisvalue = $(this).val();
                    if (thisvalue != "") {
                        $("select[name=Clients] option:not(:first)").each(function(){
                            if ($(this).attr("data-city") != thisvalue) {
                                $(this).wrap("<div></div>");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                $("select[name=Clients").change(function(){
                    alert($(this).val());
                });

    $("select").select2({
        placeholder: "choose",
        maximumSelectionSize: 1
    });
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gvhrcyum/

what i need is the first select to allow changes to the second one
and when selecting something from the first it "hide" options from the second one by a solution i found here that is cross-browser

then selecting from the client select is not retriving the right value but almost always the first one (314) or (empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues with your code:

1. You are setting `$(this).value="";` at the top of `$("select[name=ClientsCities]").change` but this is unnecessary.
2. You should initialize javascript vars. So you have this `thisvalue = $(this).val();` that should be changed to `var thisvalue = $(this).val();`
3. You are missing a closing bracket (`]`) in this selector `$("select[name=Clients")`
4. You are using `console.log($(this));` inside `$("select[name=Clients]").change()`. In this context, `$(this)` is the select and not the option. If you want to get the value of the selected option, you should use `$(this).find(":selected").val()`.
5. The empty option of `cities` doesn't have the attribute `data-city`. This will cause you issues in the JS code.

Here's the code with the changes and a forked [**working JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/ed5yvxv8/1/).

```
<select name="ClientsCities">
    <option></option>
    <option value="8">city1</option>
    <option value="14">city2</option>
    <option value="19">city3</option>
</select>
<select name="Clients">
    <!-- added data-city here so the $.wrap() works -->
    <option data-city=""></option>
    <option value="314" data-city="8">client1</option>
    <option value="315" data-city="14">client5</option>
    <option value="316" data-city="14">client2</option>
    <option value="317" data-city="19">client3</option>
    <option value="313" data-city="">client4</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select[name=ClientsCities]").change(function() {
        var dataCity = $(this).val();

        $("select[name=Clients] option").each(function() {
            if ($(this).parent().is( "div" )) {
                $(this).unwrap();
            }
        });

        if (dataCity != "") {
            // changed the selector. No need for $.each() either
            $("select[name=Clients] option:not([data-city=" + dataCity + "])")
                 .wrap("<div></div>");
        }
    });

    $("select[name=Clients]").change(function() {
        console.log($(this).find(":selected"));
        console.log($(this).find(":selected").val());
    });

    $("select").select2({
        placeholder: "choose",
        maximumSelectionSize: 1
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: ok, some of the mistakes you found: 1, 3, 5 are because i copied the wrong code to here :-s any way you help with the problem - thanks dude